# WebAPI returning different result in debug mode compared to release

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a WebAPI where I retrieve data based on a unique identification

For example

```
    [RoutePrefix("test/api/")]
    public class ObjectController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("objects/{identification}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Objects(string identification)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

I build this code in Visual Studio 2019 and host it via IIS.
The API works just fine when I send a request via postman or something similar to endpoint: https://localhost/test/api/objects/123456. So far so good.

If I for example build this code in debug mode and send a request towards https://localhost/test/api/objects/123456%20 which contains an encoded space, it'll return an HTML page with "The resource cannot be found." as message and with Http status 404 NotFound. This is what I would expect, but if I build my code in release mode I'll get a different result for some reason.

The result being:

```
404 not found

{
   "objectIdentification": "123456"
}
```

As you can see, I get a result where 404 not found is part of my response where my result is actually returned to me. My status code is also now a 200 OK.

What can cause this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

So after more some digging we came at a interesting twist in this problem. We still have some MVC controllers in our software mainly because of legacy which we are slowly removing and replacing with newer things and it turns out that one of the error handling of the MVC routing seems to mingle with the ASP NET Web API routing which is causing this weird phenomenon.

Because we now know what the cause is, we can fix it. I'm accepting this answer so others in the future with a similar case can use this as a reference.